# How to make FFI call interruptible

Tags: haskell, interrupt, ghc, ffi

According to [GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html#interruptible-foreign-calls) foreign call can be marked `interruptible`, however, I cannot make it work. I'm using `ghc 8.4.3` on GNU/Linux.

See for example this cbits.h:

```
/* cbits.h */

void loopForever();
```

cbits.c:

```
/* cbits.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "cbits.h"

void loopForever()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    printf("Tick\n");
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

And finally Test.hs:

```
-- Test.hs

{-# LANGUAGE InterruptibleFFI #-}

module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async

main :: IO ()
main = race_ loopForever $ do
  threadDelay 2000000
  putStrLn "Finished"

foreign import ccall interruptible "cbits.h"
  loopForever :: IO ()
```

I compiled it all together with `ghc -threaded -o a.out cbits.c Test.hs`.

**Now, I expected** the code to stop after 2 seconds, **however it keeps going** even after "Finished" is printed. It did mention that `This is **usually** enough to cause a blocking system call to return <...>` in user guide, so is this the case that my c function is bad in particular, or am I doing something wrong on the Haskell side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, the way the RTS attempts to interrupt the thread engaged in the foreign call is by sending it a SIGPIPE signal.  Since the handler installed by the RTS ignores the signal, the only effect is that -- if the thread is engaged in a long-running system call -- that call is likely to return immediately with an EINTR.  Since your foreign function doesn't check the return calls of `printf` and `sleep` to see if they were interrupted, the thread goes merrily on its way.

Now in an ideal world, it would be enough to modify your function to check for return values indicating that the functions had been interrupted, like so:

```
void loopForever()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    if (printf("Tick\n") < 0) break;
    if (sleep(1) != 0) break;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the interface for `sleep()` is braindead -- if it's interrupted, it returns the number of full seconds left to go, **and if this is zero -- which it always is in your function -- it returns zero**.  Sigh...

You can either switch to `usleep` which sensibly returns `-1` if interrupted, or you can use the trick of setting `errno` to zero and checking if `printf` or `sleep` change it (to EINTR, but you might as well abort on any non-zero number):

```
/* cbits.c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "cbits.h"

void loopForever()
{
  errno = 0;
  while (!errno)
  {
    printf("Tick\n");
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

That should do what you want.

Now, depending on your real-world use case, you may find it more helpful to install a SIGPIPE handler, particularly if you expect the thread to be blocked in a long running computation (without any syscalls to interrupt).  Just be sure to de-install the handler when you're done.  Here's an example:

```
/* cbits.c */

#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "cbits.h"

volatile sig_atomic_t stop = 0;

void sigpipe_handler()
{
  stop = 1;
}

void loopForever()
{
  struct sigaction oldact, newact;
  bzero(&newact, sizeof(newact));
  newact.sa_handler = sigpipe_handler;
  sigaction(SIGPIPE, &newact, &oldact);
  while (!stop)
  {
    // loop forever until interrupted
  }
  printf("Stopped!");
  sigaction(SIGPIPE, &oldact, NULL);
}
```

Comment: This is probably the right idea. Perhaps one also needs to declare `volatile int stop` (?). Further, I guess SIGPIPE could be raised before the signal handler is installed, and there's a small window for a race condition -- it could be unavoidable, though.

Comment: I added `volatile`.  I can't see what to do about the initial race, either.

Comment: Is there anything I could do if c loop is not under my control? I could set up handler and call end_loop if library provided such, but what if not?

Comment: @Cthulhu I don't think there's anything sensible to do in such case. I mean, one could try to run that call in a OS thread and then kill that thread to force its termination, but this will likely leave the C side in an inconsistent state, triggering undefined behavior the next time we enter C land if not earlier. I mean, suppose your loop is reversing a C doubly-linked list, juggling pointers as usual. You can't really interrupt that loop in the middle and hope that your pointers still form a list, i.e. that your "list" is in a consistent state.

Comment: @chi I guess it makes sense, that C is just too low level and does not provide tools for this exceptions-like flow.